# Receive custom HTTP statusCode in NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: objective-c, http, nsurlconnection

I send a GET request with `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest...]` to our web service. The server overrides the default HTTP status codes with his one codes if an error occurred.

I will test the error handling but always become a timeout (Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out.") if server send a custom HTTP code. If server sends the standard HTTP code (e.g. 400) the NSURLConnection works correct and gives me this code immediately.

Has anybody used NSURLConnection with NON-Standard HTTP failure codes and can help me to get this setup working?

Thanks

Comment: What non-standard status codes is your server sending back?

Comment: HTTP status codes are [defined as being a 3-digit integer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1). If your server is sending back anything other than that then it's not speaking HTTP, it's speaking a custom HTTP-like protocol, and you shouldn't expect HTTP clients to work with it.